# Having an issue with Jquery and animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with my code, I would like to make it so that when a link is clicked, the corresponding text bounces in and up and what ever is already on the page bounces out. I am able to achieve this, but it only works once per page load. I have a feeling its because of I am adding the classes and its not removing them until the page reloads. What can I do to not only tidy up my code but to also achieve the effect I am going for. Thank you in advance.

```
        $('#home').on('click', function(e){
            $('#aboutme-text').addClass("bounceOutUp");
            $('#portfolio-text').addClass("bounceOutUp");
            $('#projects-text').addClass("bounceOutUp");
            $('#contact-text').addClass("bounceOutUp");

            $('#my-name').removeClass("bounceOutUp");

            setTimeout("$('#my-name').show();", 500);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/26mdLrm1/

Comment: I'm unable to see the desired effect in your fiddle. The CSS panel doesn't have a class named `bounceOutUp`...

Comment: It is a part of Animate.css, the bounce effect is not the issue, its the Jquery. I think